# How to deploy / test Dialogflow chatbot to the actual Google Home device?

Tags: google-home

I created a Dialogflow project and have tested via Integration->Web Demo and Google Actions->Simulator; everything works correctly.  I now want to test it on the actual device.  My account is enabled for testing on the device - see screenshot.  However, I can't locate it when I open the Google Assistant app on my iPhone search for it, I don't find it.  What else do I have do to get in on my device?  Thanks for the help!

[image]
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't show up in the Assistant Directory until you publish it, however you can start it the same way you start it in the simulator - by saying "Hey Google, talk to *action name*"